# Find gaps between repeated numbers in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an ArrayList with a list of numbers. Each number is always between 0 - 9. So the ArrayList contains numbers something as follows:

1 2 7 4 9 1 8 8 3 2 9 0 1 3 ....

I want to count the gaps before the number repeats again. For example the number 1 has a gap of 4 before repeating again. And then it goes on to have another gap of 6. I am looking to find out gaps up to 30. The list is long. I am looking to store and produce the following:

```
Number 0 gap 1 : none
Number 0 gap 2: 5 times
Number 0 gap 3: 7 times
.....
Number 0 gap 30: none
Number 1 gap 1: 5 times
Number 1 gap 2: 3 times
......
Number 9 gap 30: 2 times
```

I really can't get my head around to how I could do this. I tried the following but it is clearly going nowhere. Looking for some direction and help please.

```
//arr is the ArrayList

int gapCount = 0;
int[] gaps = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        if(arr.get(i) == arr.get(j)){

        }
        gapCount++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a two dimensional array to keep the gaps:

`int[][] gaps = new int[10][30];`

You would use it to keep the occurrences of the gaps like this:

`gaps[0][0]` keep the gaps of `Number 0 gap 1`

`gaps[0][1]` keep the gaps of `Number 0 gap 2`

...

`gaps[1][0]` keep the gaps of `Number 1 gap 1`

and so on.

The code would look like this:

```
int[][] gaps = new int[10][30];

for (int i = 0; i < (arr.size() - 1); i++) {

    int gapCount = 0;  // reset the gap count for the actual number

    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {

        if (arr.get(i) == arr.get(j)) {

            // we only track gaps greater than zero
            if(gapCount > 0) {  
                gaps[arr.get(i)][gapCount - 1]++; // increment the gap occurrence
            }

            break; // go to the next number in the list
        }

        gapCount++;

        // we don't want to track gaps greater than 30
        if(gapCount > 30) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this has quadratic time complexity, while you could do it in linear time. I know, this wasn't required...

Comment: Fact is I have not worked much with 2d arrays though yours seems a fairly straightforward idea. My arr size is 1000 for now. Bu I get indexoutofbounds error on line gaps[arr.get(i)][gapCount - 1]++;

Comment: @kang that would mean that `arr.get(i)` is greater than 9 or `gapCount` is greater than 30. Did you add the check `if(gapCount > 30)`? I inserted it at last with an edit.

Comment: @user152468 isn't it O(n log n) because of `j = i + 1`? Not sure tho, might be wrong.

Comment: It is O(n * (n -1) / 2) which is the same as O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could work, it is really the basics of Java :

```
    List<List<Integer>> gaps = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        gaps.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    int lastPosition[] = new int[10];
    Arrays.fill(lastPosition, -1);

    for (int curIndex = 0; curIndex < arr.size(); curIndex++) {
        Integer curValue = arr.get(curIndex);
        if (lastPosition[curValue] != -1) {
            gaps.get(curValue).add(curIndex - lastPosition[curValue]);
        }
        lastPosition[curValue] = curIndex;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (gaps.get(i).isEmpty())
            System.out.print("Number " + i + ": none\n");
        else
            for (int index = 0; index < gaps.get(i).size(); index++)
                System.out.print("Number " + i + " gap " + index + " : " + gaps.get(i).get(index) + "\n");

    }
```

You should adapt it to your 30-limit of course, but that is easy.

Comment: Not sure what this is computing, but it does not seem to be an answer to the question. I tried it with Arrays.asList(1,1,2,3,2,1) and got  Number 0: none
Number 1 gap 0 : 1
Number 1 gap 1 : 4
Number 2 gap 0 : 2
Number 3: none
Number 4: none
Number 5: none
Number 6: none
Number 7: none
Number 8: none
Number 9: none

Comment: I think it is what the user wants, maybe there is a difference of 1 for the gap calculation, you can replace "gaps.get(curValue).add(curIndex - lastPosition[curValue]);" with "gaps.get(curValue).add(curIndex - lastPosition[curValue]-1);"

Comment: No. E.g. "Number 1 gap 1" should be 0 because there is no gap of size 1 between two occurrences of 1.

Answer (score 0):

One more answer:

```
public class GapFinder {

  public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> findGaps(List<Integer> input) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> lastSeen = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> result = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();
    for (int position = 0; position < 10; position++) {
        result.put(position, new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
    }
    for (int position = 0; position < input.size(); position++) {
        int number = input.get(position);
        if (lastSeen.get(number) != null) {
            int diff = position - lastSeen.get(number);
            if (result.get(number).get(diff) == null) {
                result.get(number).put(diff, 1);
            } else {
                int previous = result.get(number).get(diff);
                int incremented = previous + 1;
                result.get(number).put(diff, incremented);
            }
        }
        lastSeen.put(number, position);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```